# Max and compare condition within an embedded document array

Tags: mongodb

I've got a collection schema like this, **the dates are posted in an human readable format but they are stored as ISO dates**:

```
{
    _id : ObjectId(...)
    statuses :
    [
        {
            status: "WIP",
            date: 9/09/2015 09:31:16.205,
        },
        {
            status: "Finished",
            date: 9/09/2015 10:31:16.205,
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to retrieve every collection document which it's most recent status (`date` field) has the `"Finished"` status set.

I was struggling how to do so in the lines of`db.records.find({"statuses":{$elemMatch:{$max:date}}})` but I'm not able to accomplish the query properly as I don't realize how to compare then with the `status` field.

It may only be possible with the aggregation framework, but I'm even more lost. I'd like some guidance with this kind of query.

**EDIT:** My issue has to do more with retrieving the max date in the statuses array and then look at that document status in the same query.

**EDIT:** After some attempts, this is my closest answer.

```
db.records.aggregate([{$match : {"statuses.status":"Finished"}},{$unwind : "$statuses"},{$sort: { "date": -1}},{$limit: 1}])
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection). And I still have that question open in a browser tab from the last 2 duplicates. Long forms of `.aggregate()` with `$unwind` in the answers given there, as you need to `$sort`. Also your dates appear to be "strings", which is not going to help you.

Comment: @BlakesSeven The dates are stored in an ISO format as I remarked in the question, my main issue is how to retrieve the max date and then look at the status in the same query.

Comment: Answers there show the `.aggregate()` process to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
db.records.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $match : { "statuses.status" : "Finished" }
        },
        {
            $unwind: "$statuses"
        },
        {
            $sort: { "statuses.date":-1 }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$_id",
                current_status: { $push: "$statuses" }
            }
        },
        {
            $match : { "current_status.status" : "Finished" }
        },
        {
            $project : { _id : 1}
        }
    ])
```